# Add a folder to a zip blob

Tags: google-apps-script

`Utilities.zip(blobs)` compress all the blobs in the array argument and generate a "zip" blob.  I can create a file in Drive from this blob.

I need a zip file with folders in it (actually, I need only one folder).  Is there a way to generate a folder in a zip blob?

Or is there a way to make a blob from a folder and its content?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be easy.  Let's say I have two blobs blob1 and blob2, and I want blob1 in a folder:

```
blob1.setName('folder/' + blob1.getName());
Utilities.zip([blob1, blob2], 'zipped.zip');
```

Worked for me.

BTW, Utilities.zip() is still undocumented.  The only available "documentation" is the autocomplete hint.